# biblatex: Print label / cite key / entrykey at the end of each bibliography item

Tags: biblatex

- I strongly assume that this is a duplicate but I cannot find it!
- **The goal is to add the label /cite / entrykey of each reference at the end of each item as shown in the screenshot below.**
- The **square brackets** and the **"label:"** are not important if that is difficult to produce (nice to have).
- Another "nice to have" would be a text color option for the label / cite key / entrykey (I use red in the screenshot below).
- I am aware of the [`showkeys` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) (which was used to show the below output) but I do not want to use it because it adds too much stuff (and I do not want the label / cite key / entrykey to be printed in the margin).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% Used for demo purposes only.
% https://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys
\usepackage{showkeys}

% See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all standard `biblatex` styles and (almost?) all solid contributed `biblatex` styles you can redefine the `finentry` bibmacro to print stuff at the end of a bibliography entry.

In order to print the label after the final entry punctuation, we need a slightly tricky workaround involving `\finentrypunct`.

You can then use the field format for `entrykey` to style the output to your heart's content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{%
  \textcolor{orange}{%
    \mkbibbrackets{%
      label\addcolon\space#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\addspace}%
  \printfield{entrykey}%
  \renewcommand\finentrypunct{}%
  \finentry
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. [label: sigfridsson]]

Comment: That is great, thanks a lot!