# Biblatex: How to use/access the citation label in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For a term paper I am writing, I have to append the citation label (that is used in the text) to the citation in the bibliography.

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633215/biblatex-print-label-cite-key-entrykey-at-the-end-of-each-bibliography-item) which already helps me to append things to my bibliography entry.
However, I do not want to append the entry key but the label used in the text.

For example here:

[image: MWE]

I would like to append **(Ganshof 1975)** and **(Erler 1998)** to my bibliography, instead of *erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998* and *ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975*.

Since this also depends on the citation style, which is authoryear, while bibliography style has to be authortitle for my paper, I am not sure how to access the citation label.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, bibstyle=authortitle, maxcitenames=2, autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

% add citation label at the end of each bibliography item
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\addspace}%
  \printfield{entrykey}%
  \renewcommand\finentrypunct{}%
  \finentry
}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998,
  title = {Straftheorie - Zycha: Register},
  author = {Erler, Adalbert},
  location = {{Berlin}},
  date = {1998},
}

@book{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975,
  title = {Was ist das Lehnswesen?},
  author = {Ganshof, F. L.},
  location = {{Darmstadt}},
  edition = {4},
  date = {1975},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

First citation \autocite{ganshofWasIstLehnswesen1975} \\
Second citation \autocite{erlerStraftheorieZychaRegister1998} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around and googling I found the solution by combining the biblatex-ext authortitle style with the snippet from the answer linked above.

We can then use the bibmacro `\usebibmacro{introcite:typeset}` in the finentry bibmacro.

So the two relevant snippets are as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, introcite=false,bibstyle=ext-authortitle, maxcitenames=3, autocite=inline]{biblatex}


% add citation label at the end of each bibliography item
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\addspace}%
  \printtext{\mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{introcite:typeset}}}%
  \renewcommand\finentrypunct{}%
  \finentry
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]